# The sticky navbar isn't sticking

Tags: html, css, navbar, sticky

I have a navbar inside a `header`  which I'm trying to make `sticky` over the entire page. I have looked everywhere for solutions, and I have tried many things to solve my problem (no `overflow`,  remove the `flexbox`, set a  `height` on the parent, etc.), but to no avail unfortunately. There is just something I don't understand. I've added a class of `.sticky` to my `h1`, just to test it, and that works of course.

I've included my HTML and CSS in a snippet. Hopefully it is clear for everybody to understand it. Any help would be immensely appreciated!

Here's a link to the page: https://puzzi22.github.io/cambios-climaticos/index.html

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 3rem 0 0 0;
  background-color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 800;
  overflow-y: visible;
}

.header-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: auto;
}

.lema {
  font-weight: 400;
  order: -1;
  margin: 0;
}

.company-name {
  font-size: 3.8rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  line-height: 1;
}

.nav-links {
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.nav-links li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 3rem;
}


/* STICKY ELEMENT */

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  align-self: flex-start;
}


/* SOME CONTAINERS */

.container-desktop {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container-flex {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10%;
  align-content: center;
}


/* SOME STYLING (that shouldn't affect anything) */

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

header a {
  color: orange;
}

header a:hover {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header-flex container-desktop">
    <span class="company-name">
      <a href="#">1,5 &#8451;</a>
    </span>
    <span class="lema">No hay planeta B</span>
    <nav class="sticky">
      <ul class="nav-links">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Síntomas</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Videos</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">COP26</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<main class="container-desktop">
  <h1 class="sticky">Beginning of MAIN</h1>
  <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</main>
```

Comment: if i understand you right, you're looking for `position: fixed;` instead of `position: sticky;` (inside the css for .sticky)

Comment: The problem is that your nav bar is already at the bottom of its parent element. It's sticky in relation to its parent, which is the `header`. So, you'll never get the result you want, since the header moves out of view.

Answer (score 3):

I feel your pain. I dealt with this same frustrating issue not long ago. I found that it's because I had my sticky element within another div. So it's not allowed to stick to the top of the page. I pulled your navbar out of the div tag and it works as intended.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 3rem 0 0 0;
  background-color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 800;
  overflow-y: visible;
}

.header-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: auto;
}

.lema {
  font-weight: 400;
  order: -1;
  margin: 0;
}

.company-name {
  font-size: 3.8rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  line-height: 1;
}

.nav-links {
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.nav-links li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 3rem;
}


/* STICKY ELEMENT */

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  align-self: flex-start;
}


/* SOME CONTAINERS */

.container-desktop {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container-flex {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10%;
  align-content: center;
}


/* SOME STYLING (that shouldn't affect anything) */

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

header a {
  color: orange;
}

header a:hover {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header-flex container-desktop">
    <span class="company-name">
      <a href="#">1,5 &#8451;</a>
    </span>
    <span class="lema">No hay planeta B</span>
  </div>
</header>
<nav class="header-flex container-desktop">
      <ul class="nav-links">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Síntomas</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Videos</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">COP26</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
</nav>

<main class="container-desktop">
  <h1 class="sticky">Beginning of MAIN</h1>
  <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you! That is already very helpful. Is that considered good practice to put the <nav>  bar outside the <header>? Would there be any way to keep it in the <header> and make the sticky work? I'm guessing not...

Comment: You're welcome! I'm happy I was able to help. I wouldn't feel comfortable speaking to best practices as I'm no expert and when it comes to coding, I've found that what one person sees as gospel, another may view as blasphemy. haha. I think what prevents it from sticking is the <header> height not being equal to the full height of the page so it stops moving when you reach the bottom of whatever container the sticky element is placed in. In your original example, the <h1> element would have stopped scrolling if you made the page long enough to scroll beyond the end of the div containing <h1>.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were going for? I just put the sticky class on the header element.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 3rem 0 0 0;
  background-color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 800;
  overflow-y: visible;
}

.header-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: auto;
}

.lema {
  font-weight: 400;
  order: -1;
  margin: 0;
}

.company-name {
  font-size: 3.8rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  line-height: 1;
}

.nav-links {
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.nav-links li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 3rem;
}


/* STICKY ELEMENT */

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  align-self: flex-start;
}


/* SOME CONTAINERS */

.container-desktop {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container-flex {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10%;
  align-content: center;
}


/* SOME STYLING (that shouldn't affect anything) */

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

header a {
  color: orange;
}

header a:hover {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<header class="sticky">
  <div class="header-flex container-desktop">
    <span class="company-name">
      <a href="#">1,5 &#8451;</a>
    </span>
    <span class="lema">No hay planeta B</span>
    <nav class="sticky">
      <ul class="nav-links">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Síntomas</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Videos</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">COP26</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<main class="container-desktop">
  <h1>Beginning of MAIN</h1>
  <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</main>
```

Comment: No. I'm only looking for the "navbar" (the unordered list of anchors) to stick to the top, not the first two elements (with classes of "company-name" and "lema").